# Neo4j compare relationship properties

Tags: properties, neo4j, cypher, relationships

I need to make an optional match on relationship properties of r1 and r2.

r1 is n layers deep so I'm getting the error:

> "Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was
>   Collection"

```
MATCH (a:node{x:”foo”} )-[r1:sub*]->(b)-[r2:inst]->(c) 
USING INDEX a:node(x) 
WHERE r1.value = v2.value
RETURN b,r2,c
```

How can I compare r1.value to r2.value when I don't know the value upfront?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (a:node{x:"foo"})-[r1:sub*]->(b)-[r2:inst]->(c)
USING INDEX a:node(x)
UNWIND r1 as r
WITH b, r2, c, r
WHERE r.value = r2.value
RETURN b,r2,c
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
MATCH (a:node{x:”foo”} )-[r1:sub*]->(b)-[r2:inst]->(c) 
USING INDEX a:node(x) 
WHERE last(r1).value = v2.value
RETURN b,r2,c
```

Explanation: `r1` is collection. It's totally logical because you are specifying an arbitrary length.

So, if you need to compare **last** relationship in this chain with some specific relationship, you can use `last` function.